# Swift, How can you do math with stored numbers in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, math

This is just a project I've been working on. But I need your help. I want to do some math with numbers I stored in an array. But i don't get the coding right. Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong??

```
var primeNumbers = [Int]()

// Here I search for the prime numbers till a 100
let numbers = 2...100

for n in numbers {
       //set the flag to true initially
    var prime = true


    for var i = 2; i <= n - 1; i += 1 {

        //even division of a number thats not 1 or the number itself, not a prime number
        if n % i == 0 {
            prime = false
            break
        }
    }
    if prime == false {
}
    else {
        primeNumbers += [n]
        prime = true
    }
}

primeNumbers

//Here I want to see how to extract the prime number, with the prime //numbers stored in the array.
func ontbinden(i: Int){
    var antwoord = i % primeNumbers[0...24]
    if antwoord == 0{
        print("\(i)","is extracted by \(primeNumbers[0...24])")
    }


}
```

I want to see how I can extract prime numbers to end also on a prime number.

Help me guys!

Cheers!

Comment: C-style `for` loops are deprecated.  Replace `for var i = 2; i <= n - 1; i += 1 {` with `for i in 2..<n {`.

Comment: Did I understand your question?

Comment: Thank you! I needed that piece of code aswel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line doesn't make sense.  You can't apply a `%` to an `Int` and an Array slice of `[Int]`:

```
var antwoord = i % primeNumbers[0...24]
```

You need to select your primes one at a time.  Something like this would work:

```
func ontbinden(i: Int) {
    for prime in primeNumbers {
        if i % prime == 0 {
            print("\(i)","is divisible by \(prime)")
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `filter` to create an array of primes that divide your number:

```
func ontbinden(i: Int) {
    let result = primeNumbers.filter { prime in i % prime == 0 }
    print("\(i) is divisible by \(result)")
}

ontbinden(56)  // 56 is divisible by [2, 7]
ontbinden(30)  // 30 is divisible by [2, 3, 5]
ontbinden(42)  // 42 is divisible by [2, 3, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me out here!